# Matlab: Find string pattern with a list of words and replace in text with one word of the list

Tags: string, matlab, find

In Matlab, Consider the string:

```
str = 'text text text [[word1,word2,word3]] text text'
```

I want to isolate randomly one word of the  list ('word1','word2','word3'), say 'word2', and then write, in a possibly new file, the string:

```
strnew = 'text text text word2 text text'
```

My approach is as follows (certainly pretty bad):

Isolating the string '[[word1,word2,word3]]' can be achieved via

```
str2=regexp(str,'\[\[(.*?)\]\]','match')
```

Removing the opening and closing square brackets in the string is achieved via

```
str3=str2(3:end-2)
```

Finally we can split str3 into a list of words (stored in a cell)

```
ListOfWords = split(str3,',')
```

which outputs `{'word1'}{'word2'}{'word3'}` and I am stuck there. How can I pick one of the entries and plug it back into the initial string (or a copy of it...)? Note that the delimiters `[[` and `]]` could both be changed to `||` if it can help.

Comment: Is the desired word randomly chosen by the program, or is it known to the program which word to pick?

Comment: @Luis Mendo Randomly chosen by the program.

Comment: The `text` in your example is guaranteed not to contain `[[` or `]]`, right? Please clarify this in the question description

Comment: @Luis Mendo yes to both the question and request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

1. Use [`regexp`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) with the `'split'` option;
2. Split the middle part into words;
3. Select a random word;
4. Concatenate back.

```
str = 'text text text [[word1,word2,word3]] text text';     % input
str_split = regexp(str, '\[\[|\]\]', 'split');              % step 1
list_of_words = split(str_split{2}, ',');                   % step 2
chosen_word = list_of_words{randi(numel(list_of_words))};   % step 3
strnew = [str_split{1} chosen_word str_split{3}];           % step 4
```

Answer (score 2):

I have a horrible solution. I was trying to see if I could do it in one function call. You can... but at what cost! Abusing dynamic regular expressions like this barely counts as one function call.

I use a dynamic expression to process the comma separated list. The tricky part is selecting a random element. This is made exceedingly difficult because MATLAB's syntax doesn't support paren indexing off the result of a function call. To get around this, I stick it in a struct so I can dot index. This is terrible.

```
>> regexprep(str,'\[\[(.*)\]\]',"${struct('tmp',split(string($1),',')).tmp(randi(count($1,',')+1))}")

ans =

    'text text text word3 text text'
```

Luis definitely has the best answer, but I think it could be simplified a smidge by not using regular expressions.

```
str = 'text text text [[word1,word2,word3]] text text';                     % input
tmp = extractBetween(str,"[[","]]");                                        % step 1
tmp = split(tmp, ',');                                                      % step 2
chosen_word = tmp(randi(numel(tmp))) ;                                      % step 3
strnew = replaceBetween(str,"[[","]]",chosen_word,"Boundaries","Inclusive") % step 4
```